# How to automate a webpage clientside?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I'm looking for a way to perform automated input field filling and button submission on the clientside in a browser. I also want to write some logic based on which different form fields or buttons are to be clicked.

What is the tool of choice for this when knowing Java only, but already several years of experience?

Or could I use Seleniumhq for this? Could selenium implement some kind of "business logic" (like decimal computation) before deciding to click a specific button?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium has two versions, a basic version called Selenium IDE and a version called "Selenium WebDriver" where you can use any one of many programming languages to control your browser session.

Since you are able to control the WebDriver in Java, you would be able to incorporate your decision- or business-related logic there.